Sortable multiple selected items
I have two tables and I want to be able to drag and drop several items at once. The user selects the items through checbox and then can drag and drop them into the same or another table.
I know it is possible to drag and drop one item, but It is possible to drag and drop several items at once?


$("#table1 tbody").sortable({
  connectWith: "#table2 tbody",
  helper: function(e, item) {
    var $helper = $("<div/>");
    // Check the row that user is moving
    item.find("td").eq(0).find("input")[0].checked = true;

    const nodes = item.parent().children(":has(input:checked)").clone();
    item.data("nodes", nodes).siblings(":has(input:checked)").remove();
    return $helper.append(nodes);
  },
  start: function(e, ui) {},
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    var nodes = ui.item.data("nodes");
    ui.item.after(nodes).remove();
  },
  receive: function(e, ui) {},
  axis: "xy",
});

$("#table2 tbody").sortable({
  connectWith: "#table1 tbody",
  helper: function(e, item) {
    var $helper = $("<div/>");
    // Check the row that user is moving
    item.find("td").eq(0).find("input")[0].checked = true;

    const nodes = item.parent().children(":has(input:checked)").clone();
    item.data("nodes", nodes).siblings(":has(input:checked)").remove();
    return $helper.append(nodes);
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    var nodes = ui.item.data("nodes");
    ui.item.after(nodes).remove();
  },
  start: function(e, ui) {},
  update: function(e, ui) {},
  receive: function(e, ui) {},
  axis: "xy",
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><div><input type="checkbox"/></div></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
      <td>N1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>T1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
      <td>N2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>T2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<table id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><div><input type="checkbox"/></div></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
      <td>N3</td>
      <td>D3</td>
      <td>T3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
      <td>N4</td>
      <td>D4</td>
      <td>T4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



I have checked about multisortable but I am not able to adapt it to my requirements.

You need to use  multisortable
And you need to apply it over the table.
Working snippet:


$(function() {
  $('table.sortable').multisortable();
  $('table#list1,table#list2').sortable('option', 'connectWith', '.sortable');
});
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha384-Dziy8F2VlJQLMShA6FHWNul/veM9bCkRUaLqr199K94ntO5QUrLJBEbYegdSkkqX" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Multi-Sortable-Plugin-jQuery-UI/jquery.multisortable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.0.0/materia/bootstrap.min.css">
<table id="list1" class="sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
      </th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="contenteditable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><input type="checkbox"></div>
      </td>
      <td>N1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>T1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><input type="checkbox"></div>
      </td>
      <td>N2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>T2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><input type="checkbox"></div>
      </td>
      <td>N3</td>
      <td>D3</td>
      <td>T3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<table id="list2" class="sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
      </th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="contenteditable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><input type="checkbox"></div>
      </td>
      <td>N4</td>
      <td>D4</td>
      <td>T4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><input type="checkbox"></div>
      </td>
      <td>N5</td>
      <td>D5</td>
      <td>T5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><input type="checkbox"></div>
      </td>
      <td>N6</td>
      <td>D6</td>
      <td>T6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




@DavidMárquez  "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's How does accepting an answer work?. Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"
